# What "@" means in this host binding in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding

I have a component that uses this code in component decorator

```
host: {
   '[@.disabled]': 'config.clNoAnimation'
}
```

What does actually means? I want to convert it to HostBinding/Hostlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an animation hook.

It says

> When `config.clNoAnimation` is set to true : do not play any animations on this component

You can just leave it in the host property of the decorator though, that's the same thing as a host binding.